# How two get summary from different table with same field per table

Tags: postgresql, query

I have two table like this
[image]

As You can see the table is same field. And the different just value on additional_date on table tutorial `[{"cash": 100}, {"cash_other": 2000}]` and `[{"cash": 10}, {"cash_other": 2000}]`

How to get query for result like
[image]

I try this query

```
select user_id, additional_data, channel, count(*) as total_tran, sum(amount) as amount, mode
from (SELECT sum(tutorial.amount) AS t_trx
                  FROM tutorial
                  UNION  all
                  select sum(tutorial_1.amount) AS t_trx_bk
                  FROM tutorial_1) tutorial cross join "tutorial_1"
where "type" = 'doci'
group by "user_id", "additional_data", "channel" , "mode"
```

but get this result
[image]

for info
this summary group by (user_id, channel, additional_date, mode)

U can see demo on [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/opD7lSLB)

Comment: If someone has other query, please drop on here

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with tutorialtutorial_1 as (
select user_id, additional_data, channel, amount, mode, type from tutorial
union all
select user_id, additional_data, channel, amount, mode, type from tutorial_1
)
select user_id, additional_data, channel, count(*) as total_tran, sum(amount) as amount, mode
from tutorialtutorial_1
where type = 'doci'
group by "user_id", "additional_data", "channel" , "mode"
```